# Parse - how to add comments to an image?

Tags: arrays, parse-platform, comments, message, pfrelation

I'm trying to create an iOS application where users post and image, and then someone can comment on the image. So far I've set up the a message class which contains (among other things) the image file. I want to be able to add comments to the image, so what would be the best way of doings this.

Option A:

I could add an `array` (or `object`?) column to the already existing `message` class, and then store in this `array` the comment (`string`) and the id of the poster (`string`). For this I think I would need a two-dimensional array, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

Option B:

I could make an entire new class of `comments` which contains the user's comments (string), as well as the image file that he/she linked to (perhaps though a `PFRelation`)

Basically I'm leaning to Option A, because it seems easier/more efficient to implement, but I don't really know how I would go about creating a two-dimensional/array of objects - so my question is, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you checked https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic#model ?

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it in my app is option B. I then added a count column to the photo that was incremented/decremented onSave or onDelete. I think this method is better because it keeps the data more symmetric (with option A some data could have thousands of comments while others would have 0). Additionally, it allows you to query the comments cell if you wanted to have a notification view where you showed the user what activity has been done on their photo.